# Is this interpretation of SAS code in Python equivalent?

Tags: python, sas

I have the following SAS code

```
data output_data (keep=col1 col2 col3 col4);
    set input_data;

    by col1;

    retain col2 col3 col4;
    format col2 col3 col4 $8.

    if first.col1 then do;
        col2=.;
        col3=.;
        col4=.;
    end;
    
    if source_col2 ne col2 ne . then do;
        col3='foo';
        col4='bar';
        output;
    end;
    
    col2 = source_col2;
run;
```

I must translate it to python code. My problem is that I don't quite understand what the `source_col2 ne col2 ne .` expression evaluates to and I don't have access to a SAS environment to test my hypothesis.

Is is something like the follwing?

```py
if source_col2 is not None and col2 is not None and source_col2 != col2:
    pass
```

Comment: I think you've interpreted `source_col2 ne col2 ne .` correctly. Are you seeing any problems when you try to run this code, that we can help with?

Comment: Thanks @GreenCloakGuy. I will not be able to see its effects until the testing team checks that the output of the SAS job and my python scripts are the same from the DB and my output. Feedback will not be even close to inmediate :/

Comment: That's what unit tests are for, you build up all the possible cases you can think of and test both sets of code against them for the same output. And if one breaks in implementation then you update your tests to include those.

Comment: @Reeza I don't have access to the output of the SAS jobs, so I have to delegate the testing of data to another team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS defines this particular operator, though I don't recommend using it as it's not clear to anyone who hasn't come across this.  From [SAS Operators in expressions](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/p00iah2thp63bmn1lt20esag14lh.htm):

```
TABLE NOTE 8:  

An exception to this rule occurs when two comparison operators surround a quantity. For example, the expression x<y<z is evaluated as (x<y) and (y<z).
```

This applies to all of the "equality" operators, ie, `lt`, `le`, `gt`, `ge`, `eq`, `ne`, and `in` (though I'm not totally sure how it would apply to `in`).

In this case, the correct translation is `if source_col2 ne col2 and col2 ne .`; if `col2` is `.` then it will always be `false` no matter what `source_col2` is.  This may or may not be the desired behavior.

Example:

```
data _null_;
    if 4 ne 4 ne . then do;
        put "4 ne 4 matched";
    end;
    if 4 ne 3 ne . then do;
        put "4 ne 3 matched";
    end;
    if . ne 3 ne . then do;
        put ". ne 3 matched";
    end;
    if 4 ne . ne . then do;
        put "4 ne . matched";
    end;
    if . ne . ne . then do;
        put ". ne . matched";
    end;
    
run;
```

This returns:

```
 4 ne 3 matched
 . ne 3 matched
```

So only when the two values are unequal, *and* the right value is not missing.

Comment: Please do underline the "this may or may not be the desired behavior" part of this answer, by the way; your initial interpretation may well be the desired behavior, or it may be desired to be OR not AND.